# How to cycle through multiple buttons in the same button location

Tags: javascript, html, function, button, event-handling

I am creating a stopwatch that shows the current running time. I need to create a single button that cycles through "Start" "Stop" and "Reset".

It should start out with "Start" and when that is clicked it goes to "Stop" and later it should end at "Reset". And cycle back through them.

I haven't been able to find any guides online explaining this. And I cannot seem to figure it out on my own.

```js
        start = document.getElementById('Start');
        stop = document.getElementById('Stop');
        reset = document.getElementById('Reset');
        
        let watchRunning = false;

        Start.addEventListener('click', startHandler);
        Stop.addEventListener('click', stopHandler);
        Reset.addEventListener('click', resetHandler);

        function startHandler() {
            if (!watchRunning) {
                watchRunning = setInterval(update, 70);
            }
        }
        function stopHandler() {
            clearInterval(watchRunning);
            watchRunning = null;
        }
        function resetHandler() {
            document.getElementById("Time").innerHTML = "00.00";
            clearInterval(watchRunning);
            watchRunning = false;
        }

        update();
        var seconds;
        var milliseconds;
        var d;

        function update() {
            d = new Date();
            seconds = d.getSeconds();
            milliseconds = Math.floor((d.getMilliseconds() / 10));

            if (milliseconds < 10 && seconds < 10) {
                document.getElementById("Time").innerHTML =
                    "0" + seconds + ".0" + milliseconds;

            } else if (milliseconds < 10 && seconds >= 10) {
                document.getElementById("Time").innerHTML =
                    seconds + ".0" + milliseconds;

            } else if (milliseconds >= 0 && seconds < 10) {
                document.getElementById("Time").innerHTML =
                    "0" + seconds + "." + milliseconds;

            } else if (milliseconds >= 0 && seconds >= 10) {
                document.getElementById("Time").innerHTML =
                    seconds + "." + milliseconds;
            }
        }
```

```css
#Time {
     background-color: yellow;
     max-width: 2.3%;
}
```

```html
<h1>Stop Watch</h1>
<button id="Start">Start</button>
<button id="Stop">Stop</button>
<button id="Reset">Reset</button>
<h3>Elapsed Time:</h3>
<p id="Time"></p>
```

Comment: Instead of setting innerHTML to "00:00" you need to reset `seconds` and `milliseconds` to 0. Anyway, you can simply keep a state variable that alternates  between 0, 1 and 2. Use a single event listener that checks the state and acts accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have modified your code to create the effect you wanted. I have used jquery to hide and show buttons on click events.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
    body{
        margin: 0px;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 0px;
    }
        #Time {
     background-color: yellow;
     max-width: 2.3%;
}
.box{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-65%);    
}
</style>

</head>
<body>
<div class="box">
<h1>Stop Watch</h1>
<button id="Start">Start</button>
<button id="Stop" >Stop</button>
<button id="Reset">Reset</button>
<h3>Elapsed Time:</h3>
<p id="Time"></p>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">

$('document').ready(function(){
 $("#Stop").prop("disabled",true);
 $("#Reset").prop("disabled",true);
 $("#Stop").prop("hidden",true);
 $("#Reset").prop("hidden",true);
}); 

$('#Start').click(function(){
 $("#Stop").prop("disabled",false);
 $("#Reset").prop("disabled",true);
 $("#Stop").prop("hidden",false);
 $("#Reset").prop("hidden",true);
 $("#Start").prop("disabled",true);
 $("#Start").prop("hidden",true);
});
$('#Stop').click(function(){
 $("#Reset").prop("disabled",false);
 $("#Reset").prop("hidden",false);
 $("#Stop").prop("disabled",true);
 $("#Stop").prop("hidden",true);
});

$('#Reset').click(function(){
 $("#Start").prop("disabled",false);
 $("#Start").prop("hidden",false);
 $("#Reset").prop("disabled",true);
 $("#Reset").prop("hidden",true);
});

        start = document.getElementById('Start');
        stop = document.getElementById('Stop');
        reset = document.getElementById('Reset');

        let watchRunning = false;

        Start.addEventListener('click', startHandler);
        Stop.addEventListener('click', stopHandler);
        Reset.addEventListener('click', resetHandler);

        function startHandler() {
            if (!watchRunning) {
                watchRunning = setInterval(update, 70);
            }
        }
        function stopHandler() {
            clearInterval(watchRunning);
            watchRunning = null;
        }
        function resetHandler() {
            document.getElementById("Time").innerHTML = "00.00";
            clearInterval(watchRunning);
            watchRunning = false;
        }

        update();
        var seconds;
        var milliseconds;
        var d;

        function update() {
            d = new Date();
            seconds = d.getSeconds();
            milliseconds = Math.floor((d.getMilliseconds() / 10));

            if (milliseconds < 10 && seconds < 10) {
                document.getElementById("Time").innerHTML =
                    "0" + seconds + ".0" + milliseconds;

            } else if (milliseconds < 10 && seconds >= 10) {
                document.getElementById("Time").innerHTML =
                    seconds + ".0" + milliseconds;

            } else if (milliseconds >= 0 && seconds < 10) {
                document.getElementById("Time").innerHTML =
                    "0" + seconds + "." + milliseconds;

            } else if (milliseconds >= 0 && seconds >= 10) {
                document.getElementById("Time").innerHTML =
                    seconds + "." + milliseconds;
            }
        }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could change your thinking a little and instead of three buttons, encapsulate your idea into one, and maybe call it a Stopwatch. Every time you click the button, it goes into a next state and executes associated handler function. This is what I mean:

```
var startHandler = function (state) { console.log(state); }
var stopHandler = function (state) { console.log(state); }
var resetHandler = function (state) { console.log(state); }

var StopWatch = function (selector) {
  var states = ['Start', 'Stop', 'Reset']
  var handlers = [startHandler, stopHandler, resetHandler]
  var currentState = 0;
  var element = document.querySelector(selector);

  var clickHandler = function () {
    // Execute 'currentState', pass anything you want to handlers
    handlers[currentState](states[currentState])

    // Update currentState after, means 'move to next state'
    if (currentState < (states.length - 1)) {
      currentState++;
    } else {
      currentState = 0;
    }

    element.innerHTML = states[currentState];
  }
  return {
    init: function () {
      // Initial work
      element.addEventListener('click', clickHandler);
    },
    remove: function () {
      // Cleanup
      element.removeEventListener('click', clickHandler)
    }
  }
}

StopWatch('#stopwatch').init();
```

Here's a runnable example skeleton:

https://jsbin.com/zawomorori/edit?html,js,console